# Super Search Results Conditionals Based on Channel / Custom Field

Tags: solspace, supersearch

I would like to have a search results page with results from 8 different channels.

The results depends on the channel name.

For instance

{if channel_name = channel1}
Display {custom field} - {custom field 2}  And additional text here.
{/if}

{if channel_name = channel2}
{title} - {excerpt} - More stuff you don't see unless the results have that channel.
{/if}

{if channel_name = channel3}
{custom field 3} - {custom field 4}
{/if}

and so on.... Any idea on how to do this.  It's not clear in the documentation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try these conditionals and it didn't work? I would expect that or `channel_short_name` to work just fine in a conditional. In my test using Supersearch 2.1.3 and EE 2.7.1 this conditional works as expected:

```
{exp:super_search:results}
    <div class="search-result">
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        {if channel_short_name == "articles"}
            <p>This result is from the articles channel</p>
        {/if}
        {if channel_short_name == "recipes"}
            <p>This result is from the recipes channel</p>
        {/if}
        <p>{excerpt}</p>
    </div>
{/exp:super_search:results}
```

Comment: There is also a tutorial for this located here:
http://support.solspace.com/solution/categories/115922/folders/257413/articles/164800-searching-across-multiple-channels-displaying-content-from-different-fields